# read JSON file with u' prefix in R

Tags: json, r

I have a file JSON in a .txt file, but it contains u'' prefix in these file, etc.,

```
{u'ItemId': u'100052388', u'RealTimePlaying': u'570.3', ....
```

how could I import this file in R?

I also attach my file in this link
[my JSON file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/76i30hgpjt69yo5/logt21.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Where is the source of this file?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, I've uploaded this file (in my above post) in dropbox and I don't know how I could import this file into R???

Comment: @PhucHuynh Tim is asking because your file isn’t a valid JSON file.

Comment: @Tim, my text file is a different form of JSON file. Its structure likes JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know (not much, I'll concede), the 'u' prefix simply means those are unicode characters and I'm not sure these should pose a problem...

The package jsonlite allows you to import json files into R. If the "u" pose problem, you could consider:

1) import json in pure text.

2) use regex (either gsub from base or str_replace_all from stringr) to replace all ", u'" in text by ", '", ": u'" by ": '" and "{u'" by "{'". This can lead to some problems as it relies on the file being well formatted (always a space before the unicode for starters).

3) Convert directly to json using jsonlite.

Comment: No need to write the modified text to a file, jsonlite (and other JSON libraries) can read data from main memory.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the answer to reflect that.